# Issue withInputStream:.getInputStream()

Tags: java, android, sockets

hi mate i read from bluetoothsocket in a loop.
every read  i use myblueSock.getInputStream() without saving the input stream.
It is equivalent to open and close every time the socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should keep returning you the same input stream. It certainly doesn't amount to opening a new socket every call.

Comment: i open the socket 1 time. but i call in every iteration of loop ,getInputStream... if there are some data not read, in the next iteration with a new getInputStream, i find the data ?

Comment: Yes you will. Except you close the socket or stream explicitly in each iteration.

Comment: @dariofrongi I've already told you that "it should keep returning you the same input stream", so your question about the 'new getInputStream()' is redundant. And streams do not lose data.